# TextMode=Number is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Using a Textbox in my Web application in asp. I want to enter the quantity of the product to appear as [image]

my **aspx** code is

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4"  Width="55px" Height="39px" TextMode="Number" runat="server" min="1" max='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' step="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

and **cs page** code is

```
int quantity = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox4.Text);
```

where is wish to access the selected quantity of my TextBox4. But is shows the error that 
**The input string is not in the correct format**

Am i not using the correct input format?

Comment: what is the value in `TextBox4.Text`

Comment: What is the value for TextBox4.Text? May be some space that is creating issue. use Trim() e.g. int quantity = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox4.Text.ToString().Trim());

Comment: Please first provide your "correct input format".

Comment: @AshishRajput : space and `.` will not accepts in a textbox with `TextMode="Number"`

Comment: @un-lukcy the value is correctly diplayed

Comment: You will get this error if you not select and value from this textbox, because at that time value will be empty, and empty value cannot be converted into short

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. 1

Answer (score 2):

Set the initial text like this

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox4" Width="55px" Height="39px" TextMode="Number" runat="server" min="1" max='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' step="1" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
```

this will solve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

U can use Trim() for this single integer value.

If it was an array of values, it could have been used.

Comment: why do you expect an array coming out of a `TextBox`??

Answer (score 0):

As the `<input type="number">` is a html5 value, it is not readily available with webforms. Try this,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4"  Width="55px" Height="39px" TextMode="Number" type="number" runat="server" min="1" max='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' step="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

When we add the `type="number"` it overrides the type from `text` to `number` in the html.

This works with all versions of dot net framework and this should solve your parsing issue too..